# How can I convert my current terminal state (non-tmux) to a new tmux session?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

Often when working on a project I start by opening a single terminal and executing commands normally, and then find that I need another terminal window so I start a `tmux` session and split into 2, 3, etc panes. However, I'm working with ros and other tools and often need to execute commands like `source devel/setup.bash` etc to set up env variables and make certain tools available.

Is there an easy way to automatically convert my current terminal state (including up-arrow history, environment variables, everything `source`d, etc to a new `tmux` session? Something like `tmux new-session --from-current-state`?

I know I can use a config to automatically run commands on a new `tmux` startup but I'd rather have it flexibly use the current terminal state so that I can use it for multiple projects etc without having to write a new config file for each environment.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Tmux sessions are child processes of tmux, there's no way to change the parent of a process.

Comment: You should just get in the habit of *always* starting a tmux session, in case you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I guess I'll go with `echo "tmux" >> ~/.bashrc`...